# Jupyter Notebook - Plot inside a function - Figure is not plotted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to call a function from a class in which I want to plot several figures.
There is no error thrown but I did not receive the plot but only:

```
#############################################
Histograms of the continuous data:
#############################################
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
```

The code I use is:

```
class Pipeline:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    global plt
    from matplotlib import style
    style.use('ggplot')  


    def __init__(self,goal):
        self.goal = goal


    def examine(self,dataset):
        # Check for categorical and continous data
        continuous = []
        categorical = []
        for n,i in enumerate(dataset.columns):
            if isinstance(dataset[i][1],str):
                categorical.append(dataset.columns[n])
            else:
                continuous.append(dataset.columns[n])

        continuous_data = dataset[continuous]
        categorical_data = dataset[categorical]

        #Plot the histograms of the continuous data
        print('#############################################')
        print('Histograms of the continuous data:')
        print('#############################################')

        for col in continuous_data.columns:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = continuous_data[col].hist()
            ax.set_title(col)
            plt.show()







pipe = Pipeline('C')
pipe.examine(data)
```

I wonder because if I run the same code a second time it plots the figures just as proposed.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is this in Jupyter, cause it looks like %matplotlib inline is missing?

Comment: Yes it is in Jupyter

Comment: ok add "%matplotlib inline" at the top and run again

Comment: That was the solution. Please post it as an answer

Comment: Ok. @2Obe. Added as a solution

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It looks like you are using Jupyter. To have plots show in Jupyter you can add either

```
%matplotlib inline
```

or

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

(for a slightly more fancy plotting option)

Comment: For future readers: in Jupyterlab 0.35.4 and sympy.plotting.plot, %matplotlib inline works but the second fancy one doesn't giving me: Javascript Error: IPython is not defined

Comment: Mind also that interactive plotting with e.g. animate() is not easily possible with %matplotlib inline. Therefore %matplotlib notebook may be preferred

Comment: @RobertLugg the second one worked for me, just now.

Comment: the first one that worked for me.

Comment: does this work on databricks as well? I tried both but couldnt see the graph.